# Exercise 1.26 from Riley's "Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering" concerning proof by induction

Tags: induction, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**1.26**

The quantities $a_i$ in this exercise are all positive real numbers.

(a) show that

$$ a_1 a_2 \leqslant \left( \frac{a_1 + a_2}{2} \right) ^2 . $$

(b) hence prove, by induction on m, that

$$ a_1 a_2 . . . a_p \leqslant \left( \frac{a_1 + a_2 + . . . + a_p}{p} \right) ^p ,$$

where $p = 2^m$ with $m$ a positive integer. Note that each increase of $m$ by unity doubles the number of factors in the product.

**Attempts:**

**(a)**

Have gotten this far with (a) by showing that:
$$ \left( \frac{a_1 + a_2}{2} \right) ^2 = a_1 a_2\left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{a_1}{4 a_2} + \frac{a_2}{4a_1} \right)  $$

**(b)**

inducing from the case for m = M to the case of m = M + 1, is the same as going from p -> 2p

I figure that I'm trying to go from this expression:

$$ \left( \frac{a_1 + a_2 + . . . + a_p}{p} \right) ^p \left( a_{p+1} . . . a_{2p} \right) $$

to show that it contains this expression atleast:

$$ \left( \frac{a_1 + a_2 + . . . + a_{2p}}{2p} \right) ^{2p} $$

with guidance from a comment I figured that I can take the first expression and rewrite the second term using the induction hypothesis to give:

$$ \left( \frac{a_1 + a_2 + . . . + a_{p}}{p} \right) ^{p}\left( \frac{a_{p+1} + a_{p+2} + . . . + a_{2p}}{p} \right) ^{p} $$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've proven (a) to myself.
I've found that increasing m by 1 is the same as doubling p

Comment: Then, edit your attempt into the post.

Comment: added my attempts

Comment: You can also use the induction hypothesis on the product of $(a_{p+1}\dots a_{2p})$ as this is simply the product of $2^{m}$ numbers (or $p$ numbers). I'm not immediately sure whether that's what you need to do.

Comment: thanks, that's something to work with

Comment: I love this book, keep on reading! Chapter 17 (Eigenfunction methods) was spectacular!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that for $(a)$ you don't use the positivity of the numbers. Perhaps this will be useful in $(b)$.

Comment: The equality you wrote for (a) is wrong.

Comment: oh yeah, I see. Thanks, should be 1/2 for the $a_1 a_2$ , i guess i still have to do part (a) now. I've edited it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) This is the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality):
$$0\leq(a_1-a_2)^2=(a_1+a_2)^2-4a_1a_2$$

(b) Let $j_1=\left( \frac{a_1 + a_2 + . . . + a_{p}}{p} \right)$, $j_2=\left( \frac{a_{p+1} + a_{p+2} + . . . + a_{2p}}{p} \right)$. Use (a):
$$j_1j_2\leq\left( \frac{j_1 + j_2}{2} \right) ^2$$
So
$$ \left( \frac{a_1 + a_2 + . . . + a_{p}}{p} \right)^p \left( \frac{a_{p+1} + a_{p+2} + . . . + a_{2p}}{p} \right)^p\leq
\left( \frac{a_1 + ...+a_p +a_{p+1}+ . . . + a_{2p}}{2p} \right)^{2p} $$
As I said in the comments, this book is really great, keep it up!

Comment: thanks very much, 
so I should have been paying more attention to the form of (a), and then been trying to replicate it in (b). And when trying to prove (a) I had a complete wrong approach. 
Thanks, learned a lot. 
I am enjoying the book so far, hoping to go through it all eventually :D

Comment: @Dimbles very often, if a question has multiple parts, you will need to use earlier parts to solve later ones.